# DWithin implementation in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, filter

I have a question about GeoServer comportment when sending a GetFeature request with a DWithin filter.

```
<wfs:GetFeature version="2.0.0" service="WFS" outputFormat="JSON"  count="10"
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd">

<wfs:Query typeNames="myFeature">
    <wfs:PropertyName>label</wfs:PropertyName>
    <fes:Filter xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
        <fes:And>
            <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo matchAction="ANY" >
                <fes:ValueReference>label</fes:ValueReference>
                <fes:Literal>XXXX</fes:Literal>
            </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <fes:DWithin>
                <fes:ValueReference>geom</fes:ValueReference>
                <gml:Point srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:pos>43.55749 1.525864</gml:pos>
                </gml:Point>
                <fes:Distance>100</fes:Distance>
            </fes:DWithin>
        </fes:And>
    </fes:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
```

Considering this defect : https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-937, I suppose the unit uses for the distance by GeoServer is the degree (unit defined by the coordinate system of data: EPSG:4326).

But in my PostGIS log, I can see this request:

```
ST_DWithin("geom",ST_GeomFromText('POINT (1.525864 43.55749)', 4326),0.001035624608029343))
```

Why does GeoServer apply a transformation on my distance value?

Comment: In what coordinate reference system your source data are?

Comment: Data are stored in 4326

Comment: did you look through the code to see what is happening?

Comment: And is EPSG:4326 also the default CRS of this featuretype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance is transformated by Geotools in [org.geotools.data.jdbc.PostgisFilterToSQL](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-postgis/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/postgis/PostgisFilterToSQL.java) :

```
protected double getDistanceInNativeUnits(DistanceBufferOperator operator) {
    if (currentSRID == null) {
        return operator.getDistance();
    }
    try {
        CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.getHorizontalCRS(CRS.decode("EPSG:" + currentSRID));
        double distanceMeters = getDistanceInMeters(operator);
        if (crs instanceof GeographicCRS) {
            double sizeDegree = 110574.2727;
            Coordinate center = getReferenceGeometryCentroid(operator);
            if (center != null) {
                double cosLat = Math.cos(Math.PI * center.y / 180.0);
                double latAdjustment = Math.sqrt(1 + cosLat * cosLat) / Math.sqrt(2.0);
                sizeDegree *= latAdjustment;
            }

            return distanceMeters / sizeDegree;
        } else {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Unit<Length> unit = (Unit<Length>) crs.getCoordinateSystem().getAxis(0).getUnit();
            if (unit == null) {
                return distanceMeters;
            } else {
                UnitConverter converter = SI.METRE.getConverterTo(unit);
                return converter.convert(distanceMeters);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(
                Level.FINE,
                "Failed to turn the distance of spatial "
                        + "filter into native units, using it as a pure number instead",
                e);
        // tried, fall back on pure value
        return operator.getDistance();
    }
}
```

So by default the unit distance in the filter is Meter. this distance is tranformated in degrees by geotools.