# WFS request with DWITHIN operator returning wrong result for states within 1 kilometer

Tags: geoserver, geometry, distance, wfs, cql-filter

I am trying to retrieve US states from a point within 1 kilometer using a Web Feature Service (WFS) request with a Common Query Language (CQL) filter. I am using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/planning_map/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=planning_map%3Astates&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&CQL_FILTER=DWITHIN(the_geom,Point(-88%2038),1,kilometers)&propertyName=STATE_NAME
```

However, the request is returning three US states, which seems wrong to me. How can there be three states within 1 kilometer from a point?

Output :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "states.1",
            "geometry": null,
            "properties": {
                "STATE_NAME": "Illinois"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "states.7",
            "geometry": null,
            "properties": {
                "STATE_NAME": "Kentucky"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "states.44",
            "geometry": null,
            "properties": {
                "STATE_NAME": "Indiana"
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalFeatures": 3,
    "numberMatched": 3,
    "numberReturned": 3,
    "timeStamp": "2022-12-20T11:00:14.045Z",
    "crs": null
}
```

Why I am getting this result and how can I fix it?

Comment: Searching the web for posts on a similar topic, it looks like geoserver uses degrees and not kilometers in any case. Try with both 0.01 (about a km at 38deg of latitude) and 0.03 as the filtering distance. If you get Indiana in the first case and Indiana & Illinois in the second, then most likely it's based on degrees. Your ref coordinate is close from the state border !

Comment: @Kasper I have tried using distance values of 0.01 and 0.03 degrees, and the result was exactly as you described. I got Indiana in the first case and Indiana & Illinois in the second case, which suggests that the distance unit used by GeoServer is indeed degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your data source is a shapefile in degrees and a shapefile datastore doesn't support converting kilometres to degrees or visa versa, so your query returns all states within 1 degree of your point.

If your datastore was a [postgis database this would work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/363005/79), I'm not sure if there are other datastores that support that sort of transformation though.

Comment: I have decided to use a PostGIS database as the data store for my data, and specify a distance value in kilometers in the DWITHIN operator. This allows me to filter features based on the actual distance in kilometers from the reference point.

But I am concerned about the process of exporting my data from GeoServer to a PostGIS database, as I have hundred's of datasets.

However, I think it's worth considering the benefits of using a PostGIS database as the data store for my data.